# Any science behind folk remedies for mosquito bites?

Tags: natural-remedies, entomology, vinegar

My child is one of those people who is [really attractive to mosquitoes](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2891/do-mosquitoes-prefer-certain-blood-types-plus), and she tends to obsess and itch them open — gross. This has prompted much well-meaning folk advice about itches, like this:

[image: "natural relief" infographic]

So, in text form:

- inside of banana peel
- paste of baking soda
- apple cider vinegar
- lavender essential oil
- tea tree oil
- lemon slice
- slice of onion (this one often recommended as particularly effective)

And, not in the picture, but basil has also been suggested.

**Do these remedies relieve the itching of mosquito bites?**

(I found a number of questions here about natural mosquito *repellents* — let's assume it's too late for that.)

Comment: @Sancho I haven't seen that particular claim; I'm just putting it out there as a readily-available treatment for which there _is_ [estabilished](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11096377) benefit. I'd be interested in any non-anecdotal evidence demonstrating _any actual benefit whatsoever_.

Comment: I made an edit that I think focuses the question more directly on the claim actually made. Please feel free to change if you think I've missed your point.

Comment: That's fine — I just wanted to give a little more background to explain why I've turned to asking this _here_. If the more focused question is more likely to get good answers, I'm all for it.

Comment: Off hand, tea tree oil actually has [antiviral, antibacterial, and antifungal](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/do-essential-oils-safely-and-effectively-treat-constipation-stomach-aches-and-f/14608#14608) properties, but what exactly are you looking for with regards to reliving them? Do you mean having them itch less, not get infected, etc.?

Comment: @rob: Itch less.

Comment: Another method _claimed_ to relieve the itching is heat - http://lifehacker.com/use-a-hot-spoon-to-instantly-relieve-itchy-bug-bites-615912899

Comment: This is a likely source for the [Lavender oil part](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ptr.1103/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false)

Comment: This question is too broad - if someone finds an answer to the onion question, they can't provide it until they also answer the apple-cider vinegar question. Please choose one of the six for us to investigate and, if necessary, raise other questions for the others.